# Regular expression to duplicate each line, add separator, prefix

Tags: regex, textwrangler

I would like to have a regular expression that I can use in TextWrangler. I've read that substituting for \n+ will allow me to add the suffix but I do not know how to duplicate and add the separator.

**Input:**

```
A
B
C
```

**Output**

```
A_A_suffix
B_B_suffix
C_C_suffix
```

Comment: Thanks for reformatting, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot confirm about TextWrangler right now since don't have my mac, but you can use this regex which will work on Notepad++ and Sublime:

```
(.+)
```

With this replacement string:

```
$1_$1_suffix
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qD4yH3/1)**

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks very much! And thanks to your post, i've been using the https://regex101.com site a lot.

Comment: @Bobby glad to help. Also you can play with debuggex.com to see your regex in a pretty diagram

Comment: In TextWrangler the replacement string should be \1_\1_suffix